# How does C# Cryptostream know the keys are invalid?

Tags: c#

I am wondering how and if CryptoStream "knows" that keys are invalid? e.g. if data is decrypted using an invalid key, it throws out an error. I've seen it sometimes, but I'm not sure I understand it.

Answer (score 4):

In most crypto systems the encrypted contents are hashed prior to the encryption. The hash is stored with the encrypted data and after the decryption the hash is checked to see that the decryption succeeded

Comment: Is this default C# implementation? I've rolled this myself from time to time, but I'm wondering if it is necessary.

Comment: @Konrads all defined standards for doing encryption include this. for example read about hmac in tls here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2246

Comment: right, but that's a bolt-on, the built in ManagedAes and similar classes don't automatically generate HMAC + encryption, you need to assemble yourself